# Today Widget Not Launching On Device(works on Simulator)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

Hi I have very strange problem. My Today Widget works perfectly fine in Simulator, however when I choose to run it on real device and select 'Today' application xCode just says 'Running Today on XXX's iPhone' but on that device there is no widget. I checked in Do Not Include section and it's not there either.

I've searched a lot and most of the people has three type of problems:

1. Missing 64 bit architecture. My configuration is:
   [image]
2. Different app and extension prefix - mine are exactly the same(of course with .TodayWidget addition for the widget)
3. Some internal crash in the widget - however when this happens you could see at least the widget title. Moreover my widget is working fine in simulator.

So any advice will be highly appreciated? I've tried clean project, removing it from device restarting xCode... I'm working with xCode 6.2 and tried on iPhone 5(iOS 8.2) and iPhone 6+(8.2)

UPDATE

Updating devices to iOS 8.3 hence the xCode to 6.3 seems to resolve the problem. However I'm worried if it'll work on other iOS 8.2 devices.

SOLUTION

As @gaRik pointed my widget deployment target was set to 8.3 which caused widget to fail on 8.2 devices.

Comment: Did you selected the extension target in the schemes list for running ?

Comment: Yep it's selected there. Strange thing happens now - I've updated xCode to 6.3 and 6+ to 8.3 and now on 6+ today widget appears, however iPhone 5 with 8.2 still has the same problems?

Comment: Check Widget target(Build Settings -> iOS Deployment Target(must be less or equal as iOS version on your device))

Comment: @gaRik please add this as an answer so I can accept it. Indeed my deployment target was too high.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check Widget target(Build Settings -> iOS Deployment Target(must be less or equal as iOS version on your device))

Comment: Thanks @gaRik,  But in my case i have setup target version is 14.2 and my device version is 14.4 still not working its showing black part of Widget in simulator work perfect as i have done design.