# Today Widget Not Showing on Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, today-extension, ios9-today-widget

This problem is very strange, my Today widget work smoothly in Simulator but in my device (iPhone 5) is only showing the header of the Widget with the icon and the title.

I have read those questions but didn't solve my problem:

1. [Today Widget Not Launching On Device(works on Simulator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669848/today-widget-not-launching-on-deviceworks-on-simulator)
2. [iOS App Today Extension not uploaded to physical device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680915/ios-app-today-extension-not-uploaded-to-physical-device?rq=1)

My project settings:

- My `Development Target` for both targets is the same: iOS `9.2`
- Widget's `Scheme` is ok, with `Executable` my main app

Did you have any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: In your ios device which version is use?

Comment: @PramodTapaniya My iOS version of my iPhone is 9.2.1

Comment: Set development Target for both targets iOS 9.0 and than test.

Comment: Exactly the same results, in simulator works nicely but in my device I only see the icon and the title of the widget

Comment: Did you find the issue? I am facing the same thing on iOS 9.3

Answer (score 16):

It sounds like there are a couple of different widget problems here.

In my case, the widget DIDN'T EXIST on the deployment phone, but did on the simulator.

The deployment target OS for the widget was set higher than the OS on the deployment phone.  Setting the widget deployment target to 9.0 (making it the same as the main app deployment target and less than the OS on the deployment phone) solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Peter ! I didn't remember how I solve this problem, I had checked the deployment target as you say, with no result. I remember that I change some build and info settings and after many tries, the widget worked like a charm!

Comment: I have the same problem, the Widget extension deployment info has higher value than main app. To fix it, make sure widget and main app has the same.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the app from your device and re-run XCode - that solved it for me.

I also had to set the iOS Deployment version to match that of my app, which made it show up on the simulator, but not on my device.